# Date regexp and string comparison

Tags: java, string, text-parsing

- What is available: a string of unkown format, current date.
- What can be provided: date regexp
- What needs to be done: parse string according to specified date regexp and obtain date

Details: I'm actually trying to extract a date from the file name. Some regexp or something similar can be provided through config.

So the question is devided in two parts:

- What exactly should be provided in
  the config (just regexp or should I
  use cosum simple stuff or maybe
  certain libs exist)?
- What's the most
  optimal processing algorithm (i.e.
  there's a string, and I can call
  matches on it, but that's gonna
  result in trying all the possible
  substrings)?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly are you asking. Do you get the regex from the user? How do you know what format the date is in?

Comment: User should define the format and he is the source of pattern for the date, weather it's regexp or, as was suggested, a SimpleDateFormatter doesn't acvtually matter as long as it can be written into xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What exactly should be provided in the config (just regexp or should I use cosum simple stuff or maybe certain libs exist)?**

I'm not sure a regular expression is the right approach here. Even if you *do* create capture groups for year / month / date and so on, how would you let the user define which capture group corresponds to which data?

I would suggest you have a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The format string accepted by this class is fairly flexible and user-friendly. An example is given

4 Jul 2001 12:08:56

you can match it with `"d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

> **What's the most optimal processing algorithm (i.e. there's a string, and I can call matches on it, but that's gonna result in trying all the possible substrings)?**

The `SimpleDateFormat` is capable of parsing dates, given the format string.